# simple question on probabilty, choosing balls

Tags: probability

Question: An urn contains $n$ red and $m$ blue balls. They are withdrawn one at a time until a total of $r$ red balls have been withdrawn. Find the probability that a total of $k$ balls are withdrawn.

My attempt:

```
let A=event that first k-1 draws will get r-1 red balls
let B=event that last (kth) draw will get rth red ball
P(kth draw is the rth red ball)= P(A AND B) = P(A)xP(B)

P(A)=  # of  ways to draw r-1 red balls in k-1 trail
     -----------------------------------------------------
               # of ways to draw k-1 balls
```

So I got stuck; I was thinkg that

```
 RBBB *R is one way to achieve P(A AND B)
 BBBR *R is another way.
```

but the solution  for $P(A)$ is:

```
 solution: P(A)= nC(r-1) x mC(n-r) x 1/(n+m)C(k-1)
```

This solution is like assuming

```
 R1B1B2B3 * R2       is one way
 R2B4B5B6 * R3       is another way
```

Because they use nC(r-1)x mC(n-r).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want the probability that exactly $r-1$ reds are drawn in the first $k-1$ trials, **and** the $k$-th ball drawn is red.

There are $\binom{m+n}{k-1}$ equally likely ways to choose $k-1$ balls from the $m+n$ available.

There are $\binom{n}{r-1}\binom{m}{(k-1)-(r-1)}$ ways to draw $r-1$ red and therefore $(k-1)-(r-1)$ blue.

Thus the probability that in the first $k-1$ draws there are $r-1$ red is 
$$\frac{\binom{n}{r-1}\binom{m}{k-r}}{\binom{m+n}{k-1}}.$$

**Given**  this has happened, there are $n-(r-1)$ red left, and a total of $(m+n)-(k-1)$ balls left, so the (conditional) probability of drawing a red on the $k$-th trial is $\frac{n-r+1}{m+n-k+1}$. Thus our required probability is
$$ \frac{\binom{n}{r-1}\binom{m}{k-r}}{\binom{m+n}{k-1}}\cdot\frac{n-r+1}{m+n-k+1}.$$
This can be simplified in various ways.

Comment: I have a question about the your first term:  nC(r-1)x mC(k-r),

Comment: is this term define as (# of ways that you can pick r-1 red ball in the first k-1 pick)/(# of ways that you can pick k-1 balls) ?

Comment: and also, do you consider the ordering of your pick such that (Red,Blue, Blue) is different from (Blue,Red,Blue). This is my only confusion about this question, otherwise, it is ok.

Comment: (i) In these probability questions, it is easier to consider the balls distinct. It does not affect the answer. The imortant thing is that we are counting the same sort of thing in the denominator and numerator, and that the things counted in the denominator are equally likely. (ii) In the counting, because we were using "choose" we were thinking of $(r_1,b_3,b_7)$ as the same as $(b_7,r_1,b_3)$.